# Error converting data type bigint to int [SQL Server]

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, exception

I have to insert a phone number into the database using stored procedure.. But while inserting it is showing the error as

> SqlException: Error converting data
>   type bigint to int.

```
long phoneNumber = Convert.ToInt64(Phone.Text);

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone",phoneNumber);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

ie for this parameter,
DBType is Int64
SQLDbType is BigInt

I have used BigInt as the DataType of the column in SQL Server also.

So what could be going wrong here..

I find that  1999999999 [<2^32 ]is getting inserted properly and 2999999999 [>2^32]is not

Please tell if you need anymore info

Thanks in Advance

Comment: why you don't use varchar ? or char ?

Comment: phone numbers should be stored as strings anyway to preserve leading zeroes but can you post you insert statement? Also any triggers on the table?

Comment: What is the definition of @phone in the SProc, bigint?

Comment: Was the SQL column's data type `int` before? Did you change it to `bigint` recently? Did you make that change while the application is running?

Comment: @Richard.. well that was Int..and that was causing the issue. changed it to bigint and its working perfectly.. But Iam planning to store it as string as @martin , @malinois says that is a better practise.. If you could post your soluton as an answer, I can accept it..Thanks..

Comment: @shahkalpesh.. I havnt changed the type..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use varchar(10) or char(10) instead of bigint.

Answer (score 4):

see this [int, bigint, smallint, and tinyint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933198%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

> **bigint**
>   Integer (whole number) data from -2^63
>   (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) through
>   2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807).
>   Storage size is 8 bytes.
>
> **int**
>   Integer (whole number) data from -2^31
>   (-2,147,483,648) through 2^31 - 1
>   (2,147,483,647). Storage size is 4
>   bytes. The SQL-92 synonym for int is
>   integer.

OP said:

> I find that 1999999999 [<2^32 ]is
>   getting inserted properly and
>   2999999999 [>2^32]is not

`1,999,999,999` fits in an int because it is less than `2,147,483,647` but `2,999,999,999` does not because it is greater than `2,147,483,647`.

Your best bet is to use a `varchar(10)` to store the phone number.  If you have concerns about geting characters other than digits in your string, you can validate like this:

you can validate your string like this:

```
declare @PhoneNumber varchar(10)
select @PhoneNumber='123e0'
if @PhoneNumber LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
    print 'NOT NUMERIC'
else
    print 'NUMERIC'

select @PhoneNumber='1234567890'
if @PhoneNumber LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
    print 'NOT NUMERIC'
else
    print 'NUMERIC'
```

here is what you get when running the above:

```
NOT NUMERIC
NUMERIC
```